# Problem while converting code to new IR JS Compiler

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I have a simple Kotlin Multiplatform Library project that works great with Legacy JS compiler, here's a simple class code :

```kotlin
package net.mggk.kwl

import kotlin.js.JsName

class CustomFunc {
    @JsName("sayHello")
    fun sayHello() {
        println("Hello from kotlin library :D")
    }
    @JsName("multiplyPerTwo")
    fun multiplyPerTwo(x: Int): Int {
        return 2 * x
    }
}
```

And my gradle configuration for JS :

```
js(LEGACY) {
    nodejs()
}
```

I'm currently trying to migrate to the new IR compiler, i've read the migration guide and updated my gradle configuration to this :

```
js(IR) {
    nodejs{}
    binaries.executable()
}
```

And my class to this :

```kotlin
package net.mggk.kwl

import kotlin.js.JsExport

@kotlin.js.ExperimentalJsExport
@JsExport
class CustomFunc {
    fun sayHello() {
        println("Hello from kotlin library :D")
    }
    fun multiplyPerTwo(x: Int): Int {
        return 2 * x
    }
}
```

But, with this new config, no JS file is outputed by the compiler, the `package.json` file is present but no JS file.

If anyone have an idea about how to fix this, i'm currently lookig to write cross-platform libraries with kotlin, but not manage to compile a simple class is a dead end for me.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Above code works for me, and I can see generated JS output like this https://gist.github.com/findjigar/7674d408c4524ecbf58225b345432525

May be something else is wrong with what you're doing

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i start from a standard Multiplatform library project in intellij Community, can you describe how do you initialize your project ? Can you confirm that the output JS is in the build/js folder ? Thanks

Comment: Added complete steps in answer. If that works for you then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to create a project and getting correct JS output

Tool: `IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2`

- Create a new project (Gradle based + Kotlin/Multiplatform + Kotlin DSL Build script)
- Once initial setup is loaded, add `js` target in `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        nodejs()
        binaries.executable()
    }
    // ........
}
```

- Add `jsMain` source set

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    // .....
    val jsMain by getting
}
```

- Add `src/jsMain/kotlin` folder under `root`
- Add a file with any name. For example `Temp.kt`
- Copy-paste above code from question
- To go terminal and run gradle command to generate JS lib

```sh
./gradlew jsNodeProductionRun
```

- Go to `build/js/packages/<YourLibName>/kotlin/`

Open `<YourLibName>.js` file and see the generate JS code

You'll find JS code for class in the question

```js
  function CustomFunc() {
  }
  CustomFunc.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    println('Hello from kotlin library :D');
  };
  CustomFunc.prototype.multiplyPerTwo = function (x) {
    return imul(2, x);
  };
  CustomFunc.$metadata$ = {
    simpleName: 'CustomFunc',
    kind: 'class',
    interfaces: []
  };
```